# Amount of Configurations in PyCharm Professional is capped. Any way to raise their amount?

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Pro and have a limited amount of saved configurations. I am using a large amounts of scripts daily (easily over 30) and I only see a capped amount in the configurations. If I add another configuration I usually pop out an older configuration.

Any way to increase the amount of saved configurations in PyCharm? Can't seem to find an option for that in configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean *"Temporary"* configurations because the *"Permanent"* configurations aren't limited in number. You can distinguish them by the opaqueness of the icons.

> [Run/debug configurations - PyCharm 2021](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html)
>
> Permanent configurations have opaque icons while the icons of temporary configurations are semi-transparent.

Since PyCharm 2021.2 the default number of maximum *"Temporary Configurations"* is again configurable

> [Run/debug configurations - PyCharm 2021.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#create-permanent)
>
> Temporary — created every time you run or debug functions or tests.
>
> The maximum number of temporary configurations is 5. The older ones are automatically deleted when new ones are added. If necessary, you can increase this limit in Settings/Preferences | Advanced Settings | IDE | Temporary Run/Debug configurations limit.

In PyCharm 2021.1 the default number of maximum *"Temporary Configurations"* is limited to 5.

> [Run/debug configurations - PyCharm 2021.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html)
>
> **The maximum number of temporary configurations is 5.** The older ones are automatically deleted when new ones are added.

This default value is configurable in PyCharm [2020.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2020.1/run-debug-configuration.html#temp) through [2020.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2020.3/run-debug-configuration.html#temp)

> [Run/debug configurations - PyCharm 2020](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2020.1/run-debug-configuration.html#perm)
>
> **By default, five temporary run/debug configurations are allowed per project**, so when you create the sixth configuration, the one created first is removed, and so on. **To change this limit, use the Temporary configurations limit field in the Templates page of the Run/debug configurations dialog**.

However, by using *"Permanent"* configurations there isn't any limit. Here's a screenshot showing over 30 permanent run configurations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am a PyCharm user myself, but in my view relying on the IDE to recall configurations is not the best way to manage them, especially when you have so many. Why not write a script in the root directory of your project that can call whichever configuration is needed when it is needed?

My suggestion would be to use a library like `baker` or another CLI menu library to structure this. You use decorators to identify functions as `baker commands` which are then executed.

That way you can call your scripts without even opening PyCharm, but rather from the command line.

Comment: This is an interesting approach and functional approach, but having the run configurations integrated into the IDE allows ease of use by providing clickable icons, integrated dialogues, etc. It also provides access to [builtin macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#run-debug-parameters) among other things. Since you are developing inside the IDE the keyboard shortcuts are more convenient, etc...

Comment: Valid points! I see your answer addresses the question directly!